# delete [] и перемещения

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
int* a = new int[4];
++a;
--a;
delete [] a;
```

Будет валидным такой код?

А вот такой:

```
int* a = new int[4];
++a;
delete [] a;
```

Необходимо просто что бы какой нибудь указатель указывал на начало динамического выделенного массива? И как распознается длинна массива которую нужно уничтожить?

Может быть по типу? Но указатель указывает только на первый элемент в массиве, int*, а не ( * a)[4]. И как можно привести во втором коде int* к (*a)[4]? Почему нет неявного приведения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данный фрагмент кода совершенно корректный, так как оператор `delete` использует значение, хранящееся в указателе, которое равно значению, ранее полученному с использованием оператора new.

```
int* a = new int[4];
++a;
--a;
delete [] a;
```

Для оператора совершенно неважно, какое до этого в указателе было значение, и как оно изменялось. Чтобы это сделать еще более наглядным то вы можете написать, например,

```
int x;
int *px = &x;

int* a = new int[4];
px = a;
a = &x;
delete [] px;
```

Однако данный фрагмент кода

```
int* a = new int[4];
++a;
delete [] a;
```

некорректный, так как указатель `a` не содержит адрес выделенной динамически памяти. `delete` и `free` должны применятся к значению указателя полученому по `new` или `malloc`: это требование стандарта.

Обычно "под капотом" оператора new делается следующее. К запрашиваемому размеру памяти, который вы хотите выделить, добавляется к началу блока префикс, который будет хранить этот размер блока памяти. И адрес этого префикса просто вычисляется как смещение на размер слова (обычно sizeof( int) ) от начала участка памяти, адрес которой возвращается пользователю оператора new.  Это значение используется, чтобы при удалении памяти правильно оценить ее размер.

Что касается вашего второго вопроса, то вы можете написать, например,

```
int* a = new int[4];

int ( *p )[4] = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[4]>( a );
```

Comment: @wubalubadubdub Префикс выделяется перед пользовательским блоком памяти.

Comment: {prefix} {sizeof(int)} {адрес на который ссылается new} ?

Comment: @wubalubadubdub да, выглядит таким образом.

Comment: А отступ в sizeof(int) для хранения размера типа? prefix для хранения количества? А с классами так же? Странновато, это только для динамической памяти?

Comment: Кто этот префикс создает ОС или стандартная библиотека?

Comment: @Cerbo Это делает функция malloc., которая вызывается оператором new, если последний вы не переопределили.

Comment: @wubalubadubdub Интересует лишь размер памяти, который надо освободить, независимо от типа объекта, который хранился в этой памяти. Деструктор объекта вызывается до удаления блока памяти.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Такое поведение malloc требование стандарта?

Comment: Тогда зачем смещение на sizeof(int) от начала? В префиксе держат число sizeof(int)*4, а смещение то зачем?

Comment: @Cerbo Нет, это не является требованием стандарта C или C++.. Требованием стандарта является указания значения для free или delete, которое соответствует ранее полученному значению с помощью malloc или new.

Comment: @wubalubadubdub Префикс хранит размер выделенного блока памяти. Он между прочим может быть больше, чем вы запросили. например, для малых значений меньше параграфа, то есть 16 байт, выделяется обычно 16 байт, а не 1 или там 2 байта, как запросил пользователь.

Comment: @Cerbo Имейте в виду, что вы можете переопределить оператор new.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вы имели введу что prefix составляет sizeof(int), а не удаленность префикса от начала массива? Если да, тогда все понятно. Но это только в динамической памяти такое? В автоматической так же?

Comment: @wubalubadubdub Я имел в виду размер префикса. То есть выделяется единый блок памяти, а пользователю возвращается не адрес самого блока, а адрес смещения на размер префикса, в котором хранится размер блока.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow а в автоматической/статической памяти так же?

Comment: @wubalubadubdub нет. При удалении локальной либо временной переменной всегда известен ее размер - а потому хранить его отдельно не требуется.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, небольшое уточнение. Размер префикса составляет `sizeof(size_t)`, а не `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov за хранение подобной константной информации заботится компилятор еще на стадии компилирования? Верно? (ну те она не хранится в рантайме)

Comment: @wubalubadubdub  Нет, распределение статической памяти, которая между прочим не удаляется во время выполнения программы, потому и называется статической, и автоматической памяти, которая обычно связана со стеком, никак не связана с механизмом, применяемом для выделения динамической памяти.